# How to read all values of dropdown in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, testng, selenium-ide

How to read all values of dropdown in Selenium IDE?

I have a dropdown which have values in it (for eg Dates),  I need to select each value and click on submit button and generate the report again select the next value... the loop continues till the end of dropdown values.

How can i do this with Selenium IDE?

Comment: Can you post the Website URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop, the loop will cycle through the option in the dropdown.

```
    List<WebElement> dropdown = driver.findElements(locator));

    for(WebElement t : dropdown) {

        String valueText = t.getText(); 
        Select value = new Select(driver.findElement(locator);
        value.selectByVisibleText(valueText);

            buttonSubmit.click;
            }
```

Comment: He's using Selenium-IDE, so this code isn't much use to him.

Comment: Sorry did'nt notice that

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky to achieve elegantly within Selenium-IDE. As [Apjuh mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22375031/3219738), a loop would be the best way to select each value. Unfortunately, Selenium-IDE does not have any flow control commands by default. There are two choices here:

1) Implement every iteration of the loop manually. Not recommended.

2) Download and install the [Flow Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flow-control/) plugin for Selenium-IDE. I don't have any experience using it myself, but I might try it for a bit now and report back with results.

From there, it ought to be possible to construct a loop that does what you need to do.

Edit: After having done battle with Selenium-IDE for the last half-hour, I can only conclude that Selenium-IDE probably isn't the best tool for the job here! The following commands do successfully imitate a `for` loop:

```
store | 0 | i
label | loopStart
getEval | alert("i = " + storedVars.i)
store | javascript{storedVars.i++;}
gotoIf | storedVars.i < 4 | loopStart
```

...but getting it to play well with a dropdown box (e.g. selecting the option at index `i`) was proving problematic and ultimately far too much hassle for what should be a simple task. If at all possible, I think it would be worth looking into Selenium WebDriver, which would allow the use of actual code. Using C#, Apjuh's answer would perform the job perfectly well, and I imagine it didn't take him half an hour to get that far!

Comment: so are you suggesting to use Selenium WebDriver with Apjuh's answer ??

Comment: Basically, yes. Selenium-IDE can only do so much.

Comment: Is there any way to read the all values from dropdown to a variable? in IDE. i can write some script and generate the required html file for IDE.